# Workaround Thread and Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

From my main script, I want to run a thread with tkinter to visualize all the parameters of my simulation. Something relatable to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10556479/22696612).

Since, as it is well described in the linked question, "Tkinter isn't thread safe, and the general consensus is that Tkinter doesn't work in a non-main thread", and I do not want to run everything else on threads, is there another way to display a table (not in terminal) to track the parameters that I'm interested with?

I tried to adapt my code with the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60218062/22696612)

But as suspected it never prints the last "Finished" until I close the window

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Button
import threading
from Brain import AGV, IDLE
import time

class my_visual():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def visualize_params(self):
        ### Create the object Window
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.geometry('900x400')
        self.window.title('Table of AGVs')
        #window.withdraw() # hide the window
        table = ttk.Treeview(self.window, columns = ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four'), show = 'headings')
        table.heading('one',  text = 'Name')
        table.heading('two',  text = 'Battery Status')
        table.heading('three',text = 'Vehicle is empty')
        table.heading('four', text = 'State')
        table.pack(fill = 'both', expand = True)
        for i in range(len(data)):
            table.insert(parent = '', index= 'end', values = self.data[i])
        btn1 = Button(self.window, text = 'Refresh', command = self.refresh())
        btn1.pack()
        self.window.mainloop()

    def refresh(self):
        self.window.quit()
        self.window.destroy()
        self.visualize_params()

car_list = []
data = []
for i in range(0,15):
    car_list.append('car_%d' %i) 
    car_list[i] = AGV(car_list[i], 100, True, IDLE(), True)
    data.append([car_list[i].GetID(), car_list[i].GetBatteryStatus(), car_list[i].GetVehicleLoadless(), car_list[i].GetState()])
  

test = my_visual(data)
threading.Thread(target = test.visualize_params()).start()
time.sleep(1)
print("Finished")
```

And the AGV class is the following:

```
class AGV:
    _state = None
    agv_list = []
    
    def __init__(self, ID, Battery_Status, Vehicle_Empty, Current_State: State, just_switched)-> None:
        self.ID = ID
        self.Battery_Status = Battery_Status
        self.Vehicle_Empty = Vehicle_Empty
        self.just_switched = just_switched
        self.SetState(Current_State)
        AGV.agv_list.append(self)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"""\n Name: {self.ID}, Battery Status: {self.Battery_Status}, \
Vehicle Empty: {self.Vehicle_Empty}, Current State: {type(self._state).__name__}, Just Switched: {self.just_switched}"""
    
    def GetID(self)->str:
        return self.ID

    def GetBatteryStatus(self):
        return self.Battery_Status
    def SetBatteryStatus(self, battery_charge):
        self.Battery_Status = battery_charge

    def GetVehicleLoadless(self):
        return self.Vehicle_Empty
    def SetVehicleLoadless(self, agv_empty):
        self.Vehicle_Empty = agv_empty    

    def GetState(self) -> str:
        return f"{type(self._state).__name__}"
    def SetState(self, Current_State: State):
        self._state = Current_State
        self._state.agv = self
```

Is there a way to run tkinter on a thread or exists another way to display a table with the parameters without using tkinter nor printing in the terminal?

Comment: When you do `target = test.visualize_params()`, you are _not_ running `visualize_params` in a thread. You're calling it immediately, and then passing `None` to the `target`

Comment: It really doesn't look like you need threads here. And if you do, it looks like you could easily run the other code in a separate thread. It's not clear why you think you have to run tkinter in a thread.

Comment: @BryanOakley Could you explain to me why I'm not running 'visualize_param' in a thread? And how do I do it properly?

Comment: Because `test.visualize_params()` calls the function. This is how you call a function in python. So, it's called, and the result is passed to the `target` parameter. This is a fairly common mistake people make with threading. The `target` requires a [callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable) (roughly translated to mean the name of a function).